# Can Peccei-Quinn $U(1)$ symmetry be a $U(1)_R$ symmetry in supersymmetric models?

Tags: standard-model, supersymmetry, beyond-the-standard-model, axion

Is there a possibility that the global $U(1)$ of Peccei-Quinn theory can be identified with $U(1)_R$ symmetry in supersymmetric extensions of the Standard Model?